# Where are secure locations to store encryption keys in a react-native app?

Tags: react-native, security, encryption, cryptography

I have a react-native app that communicates with a server that makes calls to stripe for payment processing/customer creation. I want to ensure that requests are coming only from my app. so i figured i could create a token of sorts on the client, and encrypt it with a special key using b-crypt, then on the server side when the request comes in with the encrypted token as a parameter, i can decrypt that token with the same special key.

i understand the optimal place to store this key is in the env variables server-side, but how do you manage security of a secret key client-side in a react-native app?

Comment: You can't authenticate the client app, anybody can create or use a different client, because they have everything your original client had. It is not technically possible to securely prevent that.

Comment: Please note, that not matter what you do to authenticate your application, you need to do on the client side which is actually the side you don't trust. How can you safely put a secret into JavaScript, if you need to push it towards the client? This problem can not be solved in a secure manner.

Comment: i understand the client is not secure which is why i asked this, but why is react-native client unsecure? the application would have to be decompiled by ghidra or something to get at that secret key, correct? @MarekPuchalski

Comment: @GaborLengyel so i cant authenticate that requests to my server are coming from my application?...

Comment: Just because everyday user might have trouble to deal with accessing binaries, code decompilation, cracking obfuscation and finding secrets, skilled attacker with sufficient time will not. Authenticating application may be used as a layer of defence, but don't bet that it can not be bypassed.

Comment: im not saying it cant be bypassed at all ever, we all know with quantum computing becoming more prevalent, those computers can blow past any security. im just trying to minimize traffic, its just dealing with stripe customer account creation after all, not nuclear launch codes lol @MarekPuchalski

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After further research, I ended up revoking the accepted status of @GuruparanGiritharan. his solution (react-native-keychain) dealt with storing passwords in an OS's keychain implementation. this ended up not being the solution for my question. as my question deals with storing secrets keys in a way they wouldn't be visible in binary, de-compiling situation.

What I did was research key management services. I found this:

> **Handling secrets with dotenv**
>
> In Node.js secrets are usually loaded from env files using the dotenv
> module. This is done in order to separate the secrets from source
> code. For example an env file might look like this (reference below):

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USER=root
DB_PASS=s1mpl3
```

Now doing this in a context (potentially development) where you dont need to implement continuous integration, it's referred to a "manual provisioning"

My issue (admittedly, I did not specify a production environment in my question) is when it comes to a production environment, in my case, with visual studio app center (a CI option for React-Native apps)

**Continuing on this site for an option for key management services:**

> While this removes hardcoded secrets from source code, it doesn’t
> solve your problem completely; Now you need to find a way to provision
> your app with the .env file.
> This guide will show how you can remove the secrets from the .env file
> altogether, so that it can be safely checked into source control and
> shipped with your application.

This guide is discussing how to implement key management in the context of a production environment with continuous integration. This approach is relatively simple and straightforward, as all you need to do is create an .env file, add the keys with a variable, and add (in this tool's case) an additional run script to your main node.js start script.

Tool mentioned: ***SecretHub***
https://secrethub.io/docs/guides/nodejs/

Comment: do you find though, after the "replacement" is done, the source code will contain the env values? I can imagine you have a build step in AppCenter which does this, or have you altered the configuration of react native to wrap its call to start your app with secrethub? I now wonder where you put your secrethub config to protect it?

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to store keys on the client side.

The easiest way is to use the [Async storage](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage/) which stores data in a key value pair.
The problem with Async storage is that its nor encrypted so it wont suit your requirement.

The other option is to use the [react-native-keychain](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain) library which stores the passwords or keys in the securely in the keychain of IOS and keystore in Android. The security part will be managed by the operating system. So this is an approach that can be recommended for your requirement.

There are multiple ways to do this, these are just two options.